# SSE rounds down when it should round up

Tags: c++, x86, sse, intrinsics, rounding-error

I am working on an application that is converting Float samples in the range of -1.0 to 1.0 to signed 16bit, to ensure the output of the optimized (SSE) routines are accurate I have written a set of tests that runs the non optimized version against the SSE version and compares their output.

Before I start I have confirmed that the SSE rounding mode is set to nearest.

In my test case the formula is:

```
ratio = 65536 / 2
output = round(input * ratio)
```

For the most part the results are accurate, but on one particular input I am seeing a failure for an input of `-0.8499908447265625`.

```
-0.8499908447265625 * (65536 / 2) = -27852.5
```

The normal code correctly rounds this to `-27853`, but the SSE code rounds this to `-27852`.

Here is the SSE code in use:

```
void Float_S16(const float *in, int16_t *out, const unsigned int samples)
{
  static float ratio = 65536.0f / 2.0f;
  static __m128 mul  = _mm_set_ps1(ratio);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < samples; i += 4, in += 4, out += 4)
  {
    __m128  xin;
    __m128i con;

    xin = _mm_load_ps(in);
    xin = _mm_mul_ps(xin, mul);
    con = _mm_cvtps_epi32(xin);

    out[0] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 0);
    out[1] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 2);
    out[2] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 4);
    out[3] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 6);
  }
}
```

Self Contained Example as requested:

```
/* standard math */
float   ratio  = 65536.0f / 2.0f;
float   in [4] = {-1.0, -0.8499908447265625, 0.0, 1.0};
int16_t out[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  out[i] = round(in[i] * ratio);

/* sse math */
static __m128 mul  = _mm_set_ps1(ratio);
__m128  xin;
__m128i con;

xin = _mm_load_ps(in);
xin = _mm_mul_ps(xin, mul);
con = _mm_cvtps_epi32(xin);

int16_t outSSE[4];
outSSE[0] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 0);
outSSE[1] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 2);
outSSE[2] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 4);
outSSE[3] = _mm_extract_epi16(con, 6);

printf("Standard = %d, SSE = %d\n", out[1], outSSE[1]);
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a self-contained example program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It might be useful to save the values of the arguments before and after the execution.

Comment: That's the default behaviour for **all** floating point processing, not just SSE.  [Round half to even or banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)  is the default rounding mode according to the IEEE 754 standard. The reason is that this minimizes rounding errors when applied over many numbers while round-up guarantees there is a half-point error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although the SSE rounding mode defaults to "round to nearest", it's not the old familiar rounding method that we all learned in school, but a slightly more modern variation known as [Banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (aka unbiased rounding, convergent rounding, statistician's rounding, Dutch rounding, Gaussian rounding or odd–even rounding), which rounds to the nearest even integer value. This rounding method is supposedly better than the more traditional method, from a statistical perspective. You will see the same behaviour with functions such as [rint()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rint), and it is also the [default rounding mode for IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Roundings_to_nearest).

Note also that whereas the standard library function [round()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/round) uses the traditional rounding method, the SSE instruction [`ROUNDPS` (`_mm_round_ps`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb514047(v=vs.100).aspx) uses banker's rounding.

Comment: It should be noted that banker's rounding is the default for any floating point processing, not just for SSE

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks - I was just in the process of adding a note about the default rounding method for IEEE-754.

Comment: Can I somehow set the rounding to be in a traditional way in SSE/AVX?

Comment: @TStancek: you can change the rounding mode with [`LDMXCSR`/`_mm_setcsr`](http://qcd.phys.cmu.edu/QCDcluster/intel/vtune/reference/vc148.htm) - I don't know if any of the available modes will give you what you consider to be "traditional" rounding though.

Answer (score 8):

That's the default behaviour for **all** floating point processing, not just SSE.  [Round half to even or banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)  is the default rounding mode according to the IEEE 754 standard.

The reason this is used is that consistently rounding up (or down) results in a half-point error that accumulates when applied over even a moderate number of operations. The half points can result in some pretty significant errors - significant enough that they became a plot point in Superman 3.

Round half to even or odd though, results in both negative and positive half-point errors that eliminate each other when applied over many operations.

This is also desirable in SSE operations. SSE operations are typically used in signal processing (audio, image), engineering and statistical scenarios where a consistent rounding error would appear as noise and require additional processing to remove (if possible). Banker's rounding ensures this noise is eliminated

Comment: I think a real example, instead of the Superman movie is more interesting.

Comment: From the wiki link. "A famous instance involved a new index set up by the Vancouver Stock Exchange in 1982. It was initially set at 1000.000 (three decimal places of accuracy), and after 22 months had fallen to about 520 — whereas stock prices had generally increased in the period. The problem was caused by the index being recalculated thousands of times daily, and always being rounded down to 3 decimal places, in such a way that the rounding errors accumulated. Recalculating with better rounding gave an index value of 1098.892 at the end of the same period."