# SSE1,2,3 round() not fully follow std::round() result

Tags: c++, rounding, sse, intrinsics

I'm trying to make similar to std::round() function using SSE(1,2,3) instructions but have some issues with certain values and/or logical operators. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <emmintrin.h>

int round_int( float x ) {
    return (int) (x > 0.0f) ? (x + 0.5f) : (x - 0.5f);
}

__m128 roundf_sse(__m128 x){ 
    __m128  zero    = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
    __m128  a       = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
    __m128  b       = _mm_set1_ps(-0.5f);
    __m128  cond    = _mm_cmpgt_ps(x, zero);
    __m128  val     = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(a, cond), _mm_andnot_ps(cond, b));
    return  _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val))); 

}
 
__m128 roundf_mp(__m128 x){  
        __m128i i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(x);
        return _mm_cvtepi32_ps(i);
}
 
int main() {
    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        float x = (float)i + ((float)j/10.0f);
        
        std::cout << "x = " << x << "   ------------------------ " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "std::round = " << std::round(x) << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "round_int  = " << round_int(x) << std::endl;
        
        float m128res[4] = { 0 };
        __m128 in = _mm_set1_ps(x);
        
        _mm_store_ps(m128res, roundf_sse(in));
        std::cout << "roundf_sse = " << m128res[0] << std::endl;

        _mm_store_ps(m128res, roundf_mp(in));
        std::cout << "roundf_mp  = " << m128res[0] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Some testing done with Compiler Explorer - https://godbolt.org/z/b5b5YqEKo

Problems are:

a) roundf_mp() function, there are wrong results now an then with input values like ±6.5, ±4.5, ±2.5, ±0.5

and

b) roundf_sse() function: it tries to follow the function round_int structure (round_int results equals with std::round() output) and is based partly on [Branchless “select” (cond ? a : b) section found from this posting](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/sse-mind-the-gap/).

Any suggestions what is the reason for issue in **a** case and is there something not implemented correctly in case **b** ?

EDIT: By rounding float to int using _mm_cvttps_epi32 I get proper rounding:

```
__m128 roundf_sse(__m128 x){ 
    __m128  zero    = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
    __m128  a       = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
    __m128  b       = _mm_set1_ps(-0.5f);
    __m128  cond    = _mm_cmpgt_ps(x, zero);
    __m128  val     = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(a, cond),_mm_andnot_ps(cond, b));

    return  _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val)));
```

Would there be bottlenecks (control some certain values, limits, etc.)?

Comment: For (a) I think the answer is that `_mm_cvtps_epi32` rounds to the nearest even integer by default. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119177/3740047).

Comment: Ok, understood.

Comment: `_mm_cvtps_epi32` is like `lrint` or `(int)nearbyint(x)`, not `round`.  It uses the current FP rounding mode, not a special one that x86 doesn't support directly in HW.

Comment: Note that round-trip through integer will produce `(float)INT_MIN` for floats outside the `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` range, due to the overflow semantics of [`cvtdq2ps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtdq2ps) producing the "integer indefinite" bit pattern: MSB set, rest zero.

Comment: What do you mean?  Performance bottlenecks?  Same as in your old code; `cvtdq2ps` and `cvttdq2ps` have identical performance characteristics to each other on any CPU.  (https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: In the `roundf_sse` implementation you could compute `val` more efficiently with pure bit-logic as `(0x80000000 & x ) | 0.5f` (essentially a `copysign`).

Comment: @chtz, how? I get error because of unsigned int.

Comment: @JuhaP try `_mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(_mm_set1_ps(-0.0f), x), _mm_set1_ps(0.5f))`

Comment: @chtz, thanks, yes, I figured it out but, implemented it differently. I'll test which one gives better performance and answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2):

With help from commenters I got my problem solved and by changing the implementation technique also improved the performance of this function. There's one note: this function limits are ± 2^23. Limit can be extended by using _mm_cvtps_epi32() in float to integer conversion for values outside this range.

My original implementation with changed float to integer conversion intrinsic:

```
__m128 roundf_sse(__m128 x){                // for |x|<2^23
    __m128  zero    = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
    __m128  a       = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
    __m128  b       = _mm_set1_ps(-0.5f);
    __m128  cond    = _mm_cmpgt_ps(x, zero);
    __m128  val     = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(a, cond),_mm_andnot_ps(cond, b));

    return  _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val))); }
```

gives equal rounding with std::round() but, it is ~60% slower than std::round() (rdtsc/val) (GCC -O3 -ffast-math).

Suggested (by chtz) implementation gives same rounding but almost equal performance (rdtsc/val) as std::round() has and it also needs less code compared to my method:

```
__m128 roundf_sse(__m128 x){                // for |x|<2^23
    __m128 val = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(_mm_set1_ps(-0.0f), x), _mm_set1_ps(0.5f));
    return _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val)));
}
```

EDIT:

This implementation (actually three versions of it) works for whole range:

```
__m128 round_M(__m128 x){               // for |x| >= 2^23
    __m128 M = _mm_set1_ps(12582912.0); // "magic number [1.5*(2^24-8)]"
            x = _mm_add_ps(x, M);
            x = _mm_sub_ps(x, M);
    return x;
}

__m128 roundf_sse(__m128 x){            // speed: 2.5x slower than std::round() (rdtsc/val)
    __m128  SIGNMASK    = _mm_set1_ps(-0.0f);
    __m128  lim         = _mm_set1_ps(0x1.0p23f);
    __m128  val         = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(SIGNMASK, x), _mm_set1_ps(0.5f));
    __m128  cond        = _mm_cmpge_ps(_mm_andnot_ps(SIGNMASK, x), lim);

//            val      = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(_mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvtps_epi32(x)), cond),  // for |x|=>2^23
//                            _mm_andnot_ps(cond, _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val))))); // for |x| <2^23

//            val      = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(round_M(x), cond),  // for |x|=>2^23
//                            _mm_andnot_ps(cond, _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val))))); //  for |x|<2^23

            val      =  _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(x, cond),  //  for |x|=>2^23
                            _mm_andnot_ps(cond, _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(_mm_add_ps(x, val))))); //  for |x|<2^23


    return val;
}
```

but, much slower (rdtsc/val) compared to std::round().

Comment: Why do you need any special handling for numbers outside the +-2^23 range?  For floats that large which don't overflow an `int` (+-2^31), 1ulp is at least 1.0, so adding 0.5 should have no effect, rounding back to the original number. Or does it bump up odd numbers to even (with the default rounding FP rounding mode) before the truncating conversion gets to them?  Oh yeah, it does.  8388609 is representable, but ..09.5 rounds up to ...10  (I checked on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: To handle that would cost performance for small numbers, but you might do it by clearing the sign bit of the FP bit-pattern (with `andn` with the same `-0.0f` constant you already need), and checking for signed-integer > some value (or `_mm_cmplt_ps`), then use that to `and` or `_mm_andn_ps` the `val` before adding, so it's zero for numbers with large magnitude.

Comment: After googling this issue I found this three part research blog "Harder than it looks: rounding float to nearest integer" - https://frama-c.com/2013/05/02/Harder-than-it-looks-rounding-float-to-nearest-integer-part-1.html .

Comment: Oh right, blending with the original `f` for large inputs (instead of arranging to add `0.0`) would avoid the out-of-range conversion to int32_t that on x86 hardware gives 0x80000000.  Of course that makes the function slower than something that just works for a limited range.

Comment: Just `round_M` alone with a constant like that should work for round-to-nearest (`nearbyint`); I suspect that's how SSE4.1 `roundps` works on Intel CPUs where it decodes to 2 uops with the latency of two FP mul or FMA instruction.  (Alder Lake has lower-latency FP add, but roundps is still 8 cycles, same as 2x mul/FMA).  AMD CPUs run `roundps` in 1 uop.  Note that `roundps` only does round to nearest, or floor/ceil/trunc, not the special rounding mode of the C `round()` function.

Comment: You might want to check how `std::round` actually works internally, e.g. to see if it's branchy or if there's a trick you could use.